# grab dropdown value using jquery and pass it to the URL as querystring

Tags: jquery, url, drop-down-menu, query-string

I am trying to grab whatever is selected when user selects from the option and pass it to the current URL as querystring. What am i doing wrong? It always grabs the first option

```
var selectedOption = $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_DropDownList1 option:selected").val();

            $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_DropDownList1").change(function(e) {
                  window.location.href = 'http://somesite/events/Pages/default1.aspx?cat=' + selectedOption
            });
```

And this is the HTML I am working on.

```
<select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$DropDownList1" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_DropDownList1">
            <option value="Select Category">Select Category</option>
            <option value="All Categories">All Categories</option>
            <option value="Cancer">Cancer</option>
            <option value="Health Lecture">Health Lecture</option>
            <option value="Heart Health">Heart Health</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your jQuery to:

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_DropDownList1").change(function(e) {
window.location.href = 'http://somesite/events/Pages/default1.aspx?cat=' + $(this).val()
});
```

Comment: This question concerns a trivial problem, and a simple solution. I think it better to offer _advice_ in these situations, rather than "here's your code"; it encourages the OP to actually learn about what went wrong and how to fix it, partly so we don't end up with SO full of dupes.

Comment: The user asked what he did wrong. I simply provided the answer which he can view and learn from. It may have been trivial to you, but it was a problem for the user. Advice won't help someone learn as much as a workable answer, but thanks for your two cents.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is bad in any way, in fact thank you for contributing. I personally think it's better to give an explanation of what went wrong, _how_ to correct and in some cases some sample code. Perhaps you could add an explanation to your answer as to why your code works?

Comment: @j08691 thank you. worked like charm! 2JamWaffles: thanks for encouraging those who want to help out!

Comment: @j08691 how do I pass a different url if the selected option is 'All Categories'. For 'All Categories' the url is only 'http://somesite/events/Pages/default1.aspx'??

Comment: Try `$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl00_DropDownList1").change(function(e) {
 window.location.href = ( $(this).val() == "All Categories" ) ? 'http://somesite/events/Pages/default1.aspx':'http://somesite/events/Pages/default1.aspx?cat=' + $(this).val();

});`

Comment: Wow! amazing. I was using if (this.val()=='All Categories'{window.location.href='mysite/default.aspx'} else{THE LINK+selectedOption} }); was not working. You saved me here again! is the ? and : like if else kind of thing??

Comment: Yup, it's a ternary operation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_C.23.2C_Vala.2C_Objective-C.2C_Java.2C_JavaScript.2C_ActionScript

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the value inside the `change()` function. Right now it's grabbing the selected function and triggering the redirect after the change, so it doesn't detect the change in selection.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/MS2LF/show/).